# Need to send an email to users in a text field

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a text field which contains user names separated by comma. I need to send an email notification to all of them after clicking a button. How is it possible? I have created flow but it is sending email only to first person like person A as specified below.
A,B,C.

Need to send an email to B and C also.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

In a Record Triggered flow do the below Steps.

1. Select the option after the record is saved
2. Get the field value that stores the comma separated emails.
3. Pass That Field data to a Invocable method
4. Extract all the comma separated email ids thereby forming list of recepitants-List sendTo
5. In that invocable method call the below method.

   ```
       // Step 0: Create a master list to hold the emails we'll send
       List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails =   new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

       Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail =  new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
       System.debug('emailSet'+sendTo);
       mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
       mail.setSubject(subject);
       String body = emailHTMLBody+'</br>';
       if(String.isNotBlank(linkedRecId)) {
           String url=URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+ '/'+ linkedRecId;
           body+='<a href="'+url+'">'+hypeLinktext+'</a></br></br>';
       }
       body+='</br><p>Thank you.</p>';
       mail.setHtmlBody(body);
       mails.add(mail);
       Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To send bulk email from text field, Please try follows,

I think you need to create a trigger for that, Because I thought separating those usernames by using comma is difficult thing in flow from that text field.

So please fetch that text field data in trigger and assign those username values into any string list (if it's non email value for the users then please query user email fields based on that value string list).

And use those email address (from the list) to send bulk emails for each user in that field by apex.

You can find email sending via apex on below [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm),

Please let me know if it helps.